# How long does Four Leaf Clover last?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

The equipment item [Four Leaf Clover](https://wiki.diceydungeons.com/doku.php?id=equipment:four_leaf_clover) says it doubles the success odds of chance based items. How long does the effect last when the item is used? Will it only last until I use one chance based item? Will it last for the entire turn?